# Semicolon In String in PHP

Tags: php

I am retrieving an html document from a MySQL db through PHP, and it has semicolons in the style tags like this

`style="background-color:black;display:block"`

I've had issues with the quotes, and escaped them with slashes however I can't do the same with a semi-colon. Is there any way to escape this?

Comment: Why do you need to escape it?

Comment: well I'm using Curl to put it into a field on a webpage, and for some reason it poops out when it gets to the semi colon

Comment: What is the error message you are getting?

Comment: it simply fails to load, when for example when its <table style="background-color:red">Test</table> it loads the page, inputs the html into the field but when its <table style="background-color:red;font-size:18px">Test</table> its doesn't print anything to the screen like the source is literally completely empty, thanks for your help by the way

Comment: I am trying to post the table to a craigslist Post, nothing malicious...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I apologize everyone i didn't realize that escaping a semicolon is fundamental to sql injection, I'll explore alternatives.

Here's what I did, I did a str replace of ";" and replaced it with "\" style=\"" so that instead of stringing the attributes together in one style tag it put them in individual style attributes. When Firefox interpreted it, it combined them into one.